# How can I fit a curve to my data?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to fit a model to my data and have tried to use `glm()`. The plot of the data (black line) and prediction (violet line) look like this:

[image: plot]

Here is the code that I used to create this plot:

```
plot(cumulative_reputation ~ creation_date, json, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Reputation", type = "l")
model <- glm(cumulative_reputation ~ creation_date, data = json)
prediction <- predict(model, json)
lines(prediction ~ json$creation_date, type = "l", col = "violet")
```

How do I need to change my model to better fit my data? Would you recommend another formula (how?) or another regression model (which one?)?

---

The data:

```
json <- structure(list(creation_date = c(1689356840L, 1689366017L, 1689376446L, 
1689504809L, 1690366268L, 1690472012L, 1690478723L, 1690701972L, 
1690701973L, 1690746389L, 1690746392L, 1690831235L, 1691022236L, 
1692097787L, 1692625463L, 1692699453L, 1692828527L, 1692828527L, 
1692828550L, 1692829734L, 1692878775L, 1692879861L, 1693058927L, 
1693082719L, 1693106370L, 1693115869L, 1693120632L, 1693121481L, 
1693137142L, 1693164782L, 1693172783L, 1693175185L, 1693208767L, 
1693909005L, 1693914013L, 1693921364L, 1693928549L, 1693930560L, 
1693999563L, 1694001298L, 1694003421L, 1694003758L, 1694005624L, 
1694015620L, 1694015743L, 1694074163L, 1694153769L, 1694181062L, 
1694194729L, 1694194740L, 1694194740L, 1694194744L, 1694209208L, 
1694594207L, 1694798845L, 1694798846L, 1694809497L, 1694883734L, 
1694901062L, 1695124304L, 1695221997L, 1695222830L, 1695259750L, 
1695259766L, 1695260229L, 1695283945L, 1695329985L, 1695330735L, 
1695363048L, 1695399875L, 1695403486L, 1695409526L, 1695458043L, 
1695464399L, 1695469820L, 1695472988L, 1695479007L, 1695483407L, 
1695485270L, 1695485763L, 1695485763L, 1695493324L, 1695505234L, 
1695505235L, 1695509011L, 1695517370L, 1695527643L, 1695556326L, 
1695567795L, 1695567798L, 1695575998L, 1695576929L, 1695589633L, 
1695596154L, 1695607375L, 1695633830L, 1695657647L, 1695658242L, 
1695710762L, 1695719101L, 1695778729L, 1695778732L, 1695778735L, 
1695778738L, 1695779990L, 1695799694L, 1695803167L, 1695810886L, 
1695987623L, 1695987864L, 1695990650L, 1695997721L, 1696003824L, 
1696024093L, 1696027770L, 1696028662L, 1696038545L, 1696046051L, 
1696097203L, 1696097250L, 1696097250L, 1696101036L, 1696101257L, 
1696101872L, 1696101983L, 1696102912L, 1696102967L, 1696111940L, 
1696144869L, 1696144877L, 1696144881L, 1696169319L, 1696237646L, 
1696238300L, 1696259015L, 1696259816L, 1696260091L, 1696270227L, 
1696278982L, 1696337968L, 1696340688L, 1696343182L, 1696352722L, 
1696354067L, 1696354355L, 1696358983L, 1696362184L, 1696362194L, 
1696379980L, 1696508590L, 1696555795L, 1696575682L, 1696599720L, 
1696602862L, 1696611325L, 1696616262L, 1696642329L, 1696685716L, 
1696739523L, 1696759804L, 1696788735L, 1696862992L, 1697076323L, 
1697099063L, 1697163446L, 1697163450L, 1697168244L, 1697194759L, 
1697194913L, 1697214212L, 1697222403L, 1697223612L, 1697224553L, 
1697271450L, 1697373918L, 1697383699L, 1697501483L, 1697544484L, 
1697582312L, 1697630498L, 1697649518L, 1697659642L, 1697676746L, 
1697787984L, 1697801101L, 1697814017L, 1697830994L, 1697834267L, 
1697843680L, 1697845550L, 1697859321L, 1697936950L, 1697971058L, 
1698070352L, 1698074168L, 1698074169L, 1698149495L, 1698186786L, 
1698235448L, 1698254904L, 1698277182L, 1698317768L, 1698340492L, 
1698344426L, 1698359149L, 1698501142L, 1698501174L, 1698580503L, 
1698624071L, 1698628853L, 1698723185L, 1698767017L, 1698829028L, 
1698855017L, 1698868981L, 1698872459L, 1698879592L, 1698883931L, 
1698927141L, 1699012939L, 1699017054L, 1699184239L, 1699191972L, 
1699209478L, 1699216255L, 1699217291L, 1699221070L, 1699229197L, 
1699232280L, 1699235009L, 1699289663L, 1699300023L, 1699363331L, 
1699375795L, 1699375853L, 1699376029L, 1699386349L, 1699390358L, 
1699391947L, 1699512337L, 1699538741L, 1699604571L, 1699606998L, 
1699627712L, 1699637241L, 1699644675L, 1699674643L, 1699748809L, 
1699815554L, 1699815585L, 1699893567L, 1699929228L, 1699938336L, 
1699957903L, 1699993792L, 1700047938L, 1700047939L, 1700048340L, 
1700060510L, 1700065919L, 1700066668L, 1700147100L, 1700150186L, 
1700206652L, 1700214934L, 1700222203L, 1700222265L, 1700246199L, 
1700246412L, 1700246518L, 1700262490L, 1700344847L, 1700410285L, 
1700472323L, 1700484156L, 1700494126L, 1700495037L, 1700505233L, 
1700506691L, 1700508020L, 1700520333L, 1700525408L, 1700552413L, 
1700607318L, 1700669915L, 1700684114L, 1700732925L, 1700744565L, 
1700751797L, 1700759089L, 1700773449L, 1700773738L, 1700817735L, 
1700879851L, 1700885406L, 1700992913L, 1701096655L, 1701187202L, 
1701193869L, 1701201622L, 1701201715L, 1701201804L, 1701201836L, 
1701278503L, 1701286613L, 1701286619L, 1701286634L, 1701286638L, 
1701286647L, 1701288017L, 1701288017L, 1701288017L, 1701288017L, 
1701288017L, 1701611658L, 1701684760L, 1701688282L, 1701695612L, 
1701699984L, 1701702174L, 1701711709L, 1701712830L, 1701721615L, 
1701735846L, 1701741158L, 1701743301L, 1701789773L, 1701790803L, 
1701796788L, 1701892308L, 1701947896L, 1702003254L, 1702072657L, 
1702156294L, 1702168944L, 1702199216L, 1702550637L, 1702550638L, 
1702552209L, 1702580634L, 1702593350L, 1702596796L, 1702718920L, 
1702787250L, 1702805968L, 1702810703L, 1702868073L, 1702891958L, 
1702930891L, 1702976771L, 1703001058L, 1703009350L, 1703010405L, 
1703012506L, 1703013037L, 1703018264L, 1703021499L, 1703021522L, 
1703031841L, 1703060206L, 1703089869L, 1703094889L, 1703095102L, 
1703101208L, 1703104711L, 1703105139L, 1703173129L, 1703260352L, 
1703342423L, 1703354793L, 1703404493L, 1703417604L, 1703418817L, 
1703444545L, 1703563681L, 1703591832L, 1703684964L, 1703714793L, 
1703812538L, 1703880197L, 1703934720L, 1703942233L, 1703947358L, 
1704033575L, 1704287544L, 1704307621L, 1704315509L, 1704339520L, 
1704344041L, 1704347230L, 1704347259L, 1704349318L, 1704389385L, 
1704409136L, 1704446210L, 1704472782L, 1704479936L, 1704479956L, 
1704482779L, 1704482784L, 1704482784L, 1704482785L, 1704482785L, 
1704482788L, 1704495539L, 1704537726L, 1704537796L, 1704567782L, 
1704569249L, 1704657802L, 1704658066L, 1704658067L, 1704725386L, 
1704741637L, 1704827139L, 1704829174L, 1704831511L, 1704967894L, 
1704984397L, 1705052222L, 1705092510L, 1705096993L, 1705314332L, 
1705349083L, 1705349275L, 1705350635L, 1705350655L, 1705350731L, 
1705359177L, 1705373831L, 1705401750L, 1705401968L, 1705444279L, 
1705500735L, 1705505545L, 1705557868L, 1705630477L, 1705676150L, 
1705676417L, 1705676971L, 1705680388L, 1705844261L, 1705936990L, 
1705945195L, 1705945195L, 1705961691L, 1705962725L, 1705962817L, 
1706050538L, 1706103165L, 1706108128L, 1706124287L, 1706136720L, 
1706154290L, 1706156824L, 1706241721L, 1706241769L, 1706241781L, 
1706290836L, 1706313482L, 1706313912L, 1706423976L, 1706423980L, 
1706535470L, 1706545703L, 1706553698L, 1706594946L, 1706594947L, 
1706620960L, 1706633928L, 1706713032L, 1706798078L, 1706963119L, 
1706963133L, 1706963149L, 1706963156L, 1707260383L, 1707277008L, 
1707283745L, 1707309218L, 1707314505L, 1707315248L, 1707319815L, 
1707327350L, 1707348788L, 1707409053L, 1707417386L, 1707421030L, 
1707421100L, 1707425514L, 1707428808L, 1707428818L, 1707436118L, 
1707436741L, 1707436741L, 1707452296L, 1707465049L, 1707468078L, 
1707483811L, 1707490212L, 1707500812L, 1707521048L, 1707522297L, 
1707522564L, 1707581607L, 1707586028L, 1707660114L, 1707674129L, 
1707674156L, 1707674318L, 1707674547L, 1707833139L, 1707843223L, 
1707886959L, 1707896823L, 1707897982L, 1707901871L, 1707917671L, 
1707935985L, 1707943209L, 1707945041L, 1707946211L, 1707946237L, 
1707946440L, 1707948147L, 1707955046L, 1707960128L, 1707960800L, 
1707990822L, 1708101685L, 1708109250L, 1708124718L, 1708125739L, 
1708125743L, 1708138153L, 1708147520L, 1708148885L, 1708152134L, 
1708210750L, 1708264023L, 1708269826L, 1708273550L, 1708318697L, 
1708332724L, 1708373760L, 1708438853L, 1708438865L, 1708453102L, 
1708465891L, 1708467626L, 1708468884L, 1708476588L, 1708537884L, 
1708599258L, 1708610907L, 1708631809L, 1708639504L, 1708644844L, 
1708646401L, 1708653979L, 1708655051L, 1708671938L, 1708698894L, 
1708702580L, 1708703081L, 1708706782L, 1708711868L, 1708733641L, 
1708751346L, 1708800083L, 1708814889L, 1708836719L, 1708849339L, 
1708859069L, 1708860589L, 1708869171L, 1708877455L, 1708890644L, 
1708943702L, 1708953757L, 1708960301L, 1709019254L, 1709031840L, 
1709032098L, 1709036652L, 1709037543L, 1709037712L, 1709039768L, 
1709039950L, 1709041490L, 1709041577L, 1709043898L, 1709043913L, 
1709046565L, 1709048979L, 1709052584L, 1709058715L, 1709063134L, 
1709071210L, 1709087586L, 1709113927L, 1709116280L, 1709119075L, 
1709126316L, 1709138978L, 1709138979L, 1709138979L, 1709142656L, 
1709151286L, 1709156733L, 1709187230L, 1709187549L, 1709236614L, 
1709256733L, 1709410753L, 1709413677L, 1709413781L, 1709414123L, 
1709416120L, 1709421602L, 1709468432L, 1709471102L, 1709480521L, 
1709518118L, 1709545679L, 1709551447L, 1709568507L, 1709577934L, 
1709616236L, 1709624614L, 1709698037L, 1709759163L, 1709797369L, 
1709804664L, 1709821049L, 1709891323L, 1709910545L, 1709932126L, 
1709945526L, 1709946632L, 1709987230L, 1710001396L, 1710015518L, 
1710029261L, 1710040791L, 1710042181L, 1710047907L, 1710082516L, 
1710092946L, 1710122515L, 1710122614L, 1710141873L, 1710146449L, 
1710157393L, 1710170292L, 1710174686L, 1710174687L, 1710174688L, 
1710186371L, 1710186514L, 1710189587L, 1710189792L, 1710207242L, 
1710208716L, 1710258328L, 1710261205L, 1710266168L, 1710365957L, 
1710378957L, 1710404979L), cumulative_reputation = c(100L, 110L, 
120L, 130L, 140L, 150L, 160L, 170L, 185L, 200L, 185L, 195L, 205L, 
215L, 213L, 228L, 230L, 240L, 230L, 240L, 250L, 252L, 262L, 272L, 
282L, 292L, 302L, 312L, 322L, 332L, 342L, 352L, 362L, 372L, 382L, 
392L, 402L, 412L, 422L, 432L, 442L, 452L, 462L, 472L, 482L, 492L, 
502L, 512L, 522L, 512L, 510L, 512L, 522L, 532L, 547L, 557L, 567L, 
577L, 587L, 597L, 607L, 617L, 632L, 617L, 627L, 637L, 647L, 657L, 
672L, 682L, 692L, 707L, 717L, 727L, 737L, 747L, 745L, 755L, 757L, 
747L, 745L, 755L, 753L, 755L, 765L, 775L, 785L, 795L, 805L, 795L, 
805L, 815L, 825L, 835L, 845L, 847L, 857L, 867L, 877L, 887L, 902L, 
887L, 902L, 887L, 897L, 912L, 922L, 937L, 947L, 957L, 959L, 969L, 
979L, 989L, 999L, 1014L, 1024L, 1034L, 1044L, 1034L, 1032L, 1042L, 
1052L, 1062L, 1072L, 1082L, 1092L, 1090L, 1105L, 1090L, 1105L, 
1103L, 1113L, 1123L, 1133L, 1131L, 1141L, 1151L, 1161L, 1171L, 
1181L, 1191L, 1206L, 1191L, 1206L, 1221L, 1206L, 1221L, 1231L, 
1241L, 1251L, 1261L, 1271L, 1281L, 1291L, 1301L, 1311L, 1321L, 
1331L, 1341L, 1351L, 1349L, 1359L, 1369L, 1354L, 1369L, 1379L, 
1389L, 1399L, 1409L, 1419L, 1417L, 1415L, 1425L, 1435L, 1445L, 
1455L, 1465L, 1475L, 1485L, 1495L, 1493L, 1503L, 1513L, 1523L, 
1533L, 1531L, 1541L, 1551L, 1561L, 1571L, 1581L, 1591L, 1601L, 
1616L, 1601L, 1611L, 1621L, 1631L, 1646L, 1656L, 1666L, 1676L, 
1674L, 1672L, 1687L, 1697L, 1707L, 1717L, 1727L, 1737L, 1747L, 
1757L, 1767L, 1777L, 1787L, 1797L, 1807L, 1822L, 1820L, 1835L, 
1845L, 1855L, 1865L, 1875L, 1885L, 1895L, 1905L, 1915L, 1925L, 
1935L, 1945L, 1955L, 1965L, 1975L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2015L, 
2025L, 2035L, 2045L, 2055L, 2070L, 2080L, 2095L, 2105L, 2115L, 
2125L, 2140L, 2150L, 2160L, 2170L, 2180L, 2190L, 2200L, 2215L, 
2225L, 2235L, 2245L, 2255L, 2265L, 2280L, 2290L, 2300L, 2310L, 
2320L, 2330L, 2340L, 2350L, 2360L, 2358L, 2368L, 2378L, 2388L, 
2398L, 2408L, 2418L, 2428L, 2438L, 2453L, 2463L, 2473L, 2483L, 
2493L, 2503L, 2513L, 2523L, 2533L, 2543L, 2553L, 2563L, 2573L, 
2583L, 2593L, 2608L, 2606L, 2616L, 2631L, 2646L, 2631L, 2646L, 
2644L, 2654L, 2652L, 2650L, 2648L, 2646L, 2644L, 2646L, 2648L, 
2650L, 2652L, 2654L, 2664L, 2674L, 2684L, 2694L, 2704L, 2714L, 
2724L, 2734L, 2744L, 2754L, 2764L, 2774L, 2784L, 2794L, 2804L, 
2814L, 2824L, 2834L, 2844L, 2854L, 2864L, 2874L, 2889L, 2899L, 
2884L, 2894L, 2909L, 2919L, 2934L, 2944L, 2934L, 2944L, 2954L, 
2964L, 2974L, 2984L, 2994L, 3004L, 3014L, 3024L, 3034L, 3044L, 
3042L, 3040L, 3050L, 3060L, 3070L, 3080L, 3090L, 3088L, 3086L, 
3101L, 3111L, 3121L, 3131L, 3141L, 3151L, 3161L, 3171L, 3181L, 
3191L, 3189L, 3199L, 3209L, 3219L, 3229L, 3239L, 3249L, 3259L, 
3269L, 3267L, 3282L, 3292L, 3302L, 3312L, 3322L, 3337L, 3322L, 
3332L, 3342L, 3352L, 3362L, 3377L, 3362L, 3372L, 3362L, 3360L, 
3362L, 3372L, 3387L, 3397L, 3407L, 3417L, 3432L, 3442L, 3452L, 
3467L, 3477L, 3487L, 3497L, 3507L, 3517L, 3527L, 3537L, 3547L, 
3557L, 3567L, 3582L, 3572L, 3582L, 3597L, 3612L, 3597L, 3612L, 
3622L, 3632L, 3642L, 3652L, 3662L, 3672L, 3682L, 3697L, 3707L, 
3717L, 3727L, 3737L, 3747L, 3757L, 3767L, 3782L, 3792L, 3802L, 
3812L, 3822L, 3832L, 3842L, 3852L, 3862L, 3872L, 3882L, 3892L, 
3902L, 3912L, 3902L, 3912L, 3922L, 3932L, 3947L, 3932L, 3942L, 
3952L, 3962L, 3972L, 3987L, 3997L, 4007L, 4017L, 4027L, 4042L, 
4027L, 4042L, 4027L, 4037L, 4047L, 4057L, 4067L, 4077L, 4087L, 
4097L, 4107L, 4122L, 4132L, 4142L, 4152L, 4162L, 4172L, 4182L, 
4172L, 4182L, 4192L, 4207L, 4217L, 4227L, 4237L, 4235L, 4245L, 
4255L, 4265L, 4275L, 4285L, 4295L, 4305L, 4315L, 4325L, 4315L, 
4325L, 4340L, 4350L, 4360L, 4358L, 4368L, 4378L, 4393L, 4403L, 
4413L, 4423L, 4433L, 4443L, 4433L, 4443L, 4453L, 4463L, 4461L, 
4471L, 4481L, 4491L, 4501L, 4511L, 4521L, 4531L, 4541L, 4551L, 
4561L, 4571L, 4581L, 4591L, 4601L, 4611L, 4621L, 4631L, 4641L, 
4651L, 4641L, 4651L, 4661L, 4671L, 4681L, 4679L, 4694L, 4704L, 
4714L, 4724L, 4734L, 4744L, 4754L, 4764L, 4774L, 4784L, 4794L, 
4804L, 4814L, 4824L, 4822L, 4832L, 4842L, 4852L, 4862L, 4872L, 
4882L, 4892L, 4902L, 4912L, 4922L, 4932L, 4942L, 4940L, 4938L, 
4948L, 4958L, 4968L, 4978L, 4988L, 5003L, 5013L, 5023L, 5033L, 
5031L, 5046L, 5056L, 5066L, 5076L, 5086L, 5096L, 5106L, 5116L, 
5126L, 5136L, 5146L, 5156L, 5166L, 5176L, 5186L, 5176L, 5186L, 
5196L, 5206L, 5216L, 5226L, 5236L, 5246L, 5256L, 5266L, 5276L, 
5286L, 5296L, 5294L, 5304L, 5314L, 5324L, 5334L, 5344L, 5354L, 
5364L, 5362L, 5372L, 5382L, 5392L, 5402L, 5412L, 5422L, 5420L, 
5430L, 5445L, 5455L, 5465L, 5475L, 5485L, 5495L, 5505L, 5515L, 
5513L, 5523L, 5533L, 5543L, 5553L, 5568L, 5583L, 5593L, 5608L, 
5618L, 5628L, 5638L, 5628L, 5638L, 5648L, 5658L, 5668L, 5678L, 
5688L, 5698L, 5713L, 5723L, 5733L, 5743L, 5753L, 5763L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(670L, 
669L, 668L, 667L, 666L, 665L, 664L, 663L, 662L, 661L, 660L, 659L, 
658L, 657L, 656L, 655L, 653L, 654L, 652L, 651L, 650L, 649L, 648L, 
647L, 646L, 645L, 644L, 643L, 642L, 641L, 640L, 639L, 638L, 637L, 
636L, 635L, 634L, 633L, 632L, 631L, 630L, 629L, 628L, 627L, 626L, 
625L, 624L, 623L, 622L, 620L, 621L, 619L, 618L, 617L, 616L, 615L, 
614L, 613L, 612L, 611L, 610L, 609L, 608L, 607L, 606L, 605L, 604L, 
603L, 602L, 601L, 600L, 599L, 598L, 597L, 596L, 595L, 594L, 593L, 
592L, 590L, 591L, 589L, 588L, 587L, 586L, 585L, 584L, 583L, 582L, 
581L, 580L, 579L, 578L, 577L, 576L, 575L, 574L, 573L, 572L, 571L, 
570L, 569L, 568L, 567L, 566L, 565L, 564L, 563L, 562L, 561L, 560L, 
559L, 558L, 557L, 556L, 555L, 554L, 553L, 552L, 550L, 551L, 549L, 
548L, 547L, 546L, 545L, 544L, 543L, 542L, 541L, 540L, 539L, 538L, 
537L, 536L, 535L, 534L, 533L, 532L, 531L, 530L, 529L, 528L, 527L, 
526L, 525L, 524L, 523L, 522L, 521L, 520L, 519L, 518L, 517L, 516L, 
515L, 514L, 513L, 512L, 511L, 510L, 509L, 508L, 507L, 506L, 505L, 
504L, 503L, 502L, 501L, 500L, 499L, 498L, 497L, 496L, 495L, 494L, 
493L, 492L, 491L, 490L, 489L, 488L, 487L, 486L, 485L, 484L, 483L, 
482L, 481L, 480L, 479L, 478L, 477L, 476L, 475L, 474L, 473L, 472L, 
471L, 470L, 469L, 468L, 467L, 466L, 465L, 464L, 463L, 462L, 461L, 
460L, 459L, 458L, 457L, 456L, 455L, 454L, 453L, 452L, 451L, 450L, 
449L, 448L, 447L, 446L, 445L, 444L, 443L, 442L, 441L, 440L, 439L, 
438L, 437L, 436L, 435L, 434L, 433L, 432L, 431L, 430L, 429L, 428L, 
427L, 426L, 425L, 424L, 423L, 422L, 421L, 420L, 419L, 418L, 417L, 
416L, 415L, 414L, 413L, 412L, 411L, 410L, 409L, 408L, 407L, 406L, 
405L, 404L, 403L, 402L, 401L, 400L, 399L, 398L, 397L, 396L, 395L, 
394L, 393L, 392L, 391L, 390L, 389L, 388L, 387L, 386L, 385L, 384L, 
383L, 382L, 381L, 380L, 379L, 378L, 377L, 376L, 375L, 374L, 373L, 
372L, 371L, 370L, 369L, 368L, 367L, 366L, 365L, 364L, 363L, 362L, 
357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 356L, 355L, 354L, 353L, 352L, 351L, 
350L, 349L, 348L, 347L, 346L, 345L, 344L, 343L, 342L, 341L, 340L, 
339L, 338L, 337L, 336L, 335L, 334L, 333L, 332L, 331L, 330L, 329L, 
328L, 327L, 326L, 325L, 324L, 323L, 322L, 321L, 320L, 319L, 318L, 
317L, 316L, 315L, 314L, 313L, 312L, 311L, 310L, 309L, 308L, 307L, 
306L, 305L, 304L, 303L, 302L, 301L, 300L, 299L, 298L, 297L, 296L, 
295L, 294L, 293L, 292L, 291L, 290L, 289L, 288L, 287L, 286L, 285L, 
284L, 283L, 282L, 281L, 280L, 279L, 278L, 277L, 276L, 275L, 274L, 
273L, 272L, 270L, 271L, 268L, 269L, 267L, 266L, 265L, 264L, 263L, 
262L, 261L, 260L, 259L, 258L, 257L, 256L, 255L, 254L, 253L, 252L, 
251L, 250L, 249L, 248L, 247L, 246L, 245L, 244L, 243L, 242L, 241L, 
240L, 239L, 238L, 237L, 236L, 235L, 234L, 233L, 232L, 231L, 230L, 
229L, 228L, 226L, 227L, 225L, 224L, 223L, 222L, 221L, 220L, 219L, 
218L, 217L, 216L, 215L, 214L, 213L, 212L, 211L, 210L, 209L, 208L, 
207L, 206L, 205L, 204L, 203L, 202L, 201L, 200L, 199L, 198L, 197L, 
196L, 195L, 194L, 193L, 192L, 191L, 190L, 189L, 188L, 187L, 186L, 
185L, 184L, 183L, 182L, 181L, 180L, 179L, 178L, 176L, 177L, 175L, 
174L, 173L, 172L, 171L, 170L, 169L, 168L, 167L, 166L, 165L, 164L, 
163L, 162L, 161L, 160L, 159L, 158L, 157L, 156L, 155L, 154L, 153L, 
152L, 151L, 150L, 149L, 148L, 147L, 146L, 145L, 144L, 143L, 142L, 
141L, 140L, 139L, 138L, 137L, 136L, 135L, 134L, 133L, 132L, 131L, 
130L, 129L, 128L, 127L, 126L, 125L, 124L, 123L, 122L, 121L, 120L, 
119L, 118L, 117L, 116L, 115L, 114L, 113L, 112L, 111L, 110L, 109L, 
108L, 107L, 106L, 105L, 104L, 103L, 102L, 101L, 100L, 99L, 98L, 
97L, 96L, 95L, 94L, 93L, 92L, 91L, 90L, 89L, 88L, 87L, 86L, 85L, 
84L, 83L, 82L, 81L, 80L, 79L, 78L, 77L, 76L, 75L, 74L, 73L, 72L, 
71L, 70L, 69L, 68L, 67L, 66L, 64L, 65L, 63L, 62L, 61L, 60L, 59L, 
58L, 57L, 56L, 55L, 54L, 53L, 52L, 51L, 50L, 49L, 48L, 47L, 46L, 
45L, 44L, 43L, 42L, 41L, 40L, 39L, 38L, 37L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 
32L, 31L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 
19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L))
```

Comment: Maybe you should check out what the acronym "GLM" stands for :-)

Comment: @LuckyPal I know what it stands for. But I see many plots online where people use a generalized linear model and the predicted values represent a curve. I really don't want to study maths to create this one plot. Maybe you could help me along a bit? I'd greatly appreciate it. If not, that's fine.

Comment: cumulated values are not independent. Don't fit a model that assumes independence to cumulated values

Comment: @Glen_b So what would be a better model? (The data are my cumulated reputation on one Stack Exchange site.)

Comment: The increments are likely to be considerably easier to model but they won't be independent nor identically distributed. I don't have a good model for SE reputation, it's not something I've tried to model. I don't have any specific suggestion for a model for that (it's not something I've looked at) but clearly the cumulated values are *highly* dependent; you shouldn't treat them as if they are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have to precise which family of distribution and link function you want to use. If you don't, then the default family is gaussian and link function is linear and gives you a linear model with a straight line as it is on your graph.

However, in your case, I would say that is a good fit of your data except at the extremities. So, maybe ask yourself how much the values at the extremities are important?

Here is an example with the gaussian family function and log link function:

```
plot(cumulative_reputation ~ creation_date, json, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Reputation", type = "l")
model <- glm(cumulative_reputation ~ creation_date, family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = json)
prediction <- predict(model, json)
lines(exp(prediction) ~ json$creation_date, type = "l", col = "violet")
```

and it gives you:

[image]

You can also have a look at this Wikipedia page to gather some information about the different link functions and distributions:
[Wikipedia GLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model).